# Correct Way to Exit emacsclient When Set as the Git Editor

Tags: git, emacs, emacsclient

I'd like to use emacsclient as my editor in git, i.e. the `core.editor` setting in my `.gitconfig`. In my `.gitconfig`, I have:

```
...
[core]
  editor = /usr/local/bin/emacsclient --tty
...
```

When I do something like `git commit --amend`, or just `git commit`, I get put into emacs(client) as expected, but when trying to exit with `C-x C-c`, I get the message:

```
Don’t kill this buffer #<buffer COMMIT_EDITMSG>.  Instead cancel using C-c C-k
```

Following the suggestion to cancel above results in an obvious error from git:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/local/bin/emacsclient --tty'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

What I've discovered is that using `C-x #` *kind* of works, my changes are there. However, the next time I run something like `git commit --amend`, I get the message in emacsclient:

```
Revert buffer from file /[CONTAINING FOLDER]/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG? (yes or no)
```

so I'm guessing this isn't exactly the right way to exit. I've also tried `C-x k`, but that doesn't seem to save anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the buffer is using (one of the variants of) `git-commit` mode.

To accept the commit message use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> (control+c twice)

https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/main/lisp/git-commit.el has this commentary:

> ```
> ;; By making use of the `with-editor' package this package provides
> ;; both ways of finish an editing session.  In either case the file
> ;; is saved, but Emacseditor's exit code differs.
> ;;
> ;;   C-c C-c  Finish the editing session successfully by returning
> ;;            with exit code 0.  Git then creates the commit using
> ;;            the message it finds in the file.
> ;;
> ;;   C-c C-k  Aborts the edit editing session by returning with exit
> ;;            code 1.  Git then aborts the commit.
> ```

Comment: Yup, I should learn to read. Thank you!